# compare strings lexicographically in multiple queries

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

Compare two numbers in the form of string lexicographically multiple times.

**What I tried**

the question is straight forward, to compare string after change but I am getting Time limit exceeded error because of multiple queries.

I was searching internet and came across segment tree to solve range queries. But alas I am not able to visualise, how it can help here.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segment tree seems overkill for this problem. When will B be lexicographically larger than A? When at index i, A[i] = 0, B [i] = 1 and A[0:i] = B [0:i]. Iterate over both strings at same time and keep in a set all indexes where they are different.

For each query at index i, update B to 1. Then check if B[i] = A[i]. IF they are equal, erase i from the indexes set. Otherwise, add it to the set. If there is no index left in the set, A and B are now equal => answer YES.

If there is at least 1 element, get the lowest index. If this index is j, that means A[0:j] = B[0:j] but A[j] != B[j]. So either A is 0 and B is 1 or A is 1 and B is 0. Depending on that, answer YES or NO.

This has complexity of `O(Q log N)`, being Q the amount of queries

Comment: In theory a van Emde Boas tree can be used to reduce the complexity to O(Q log log N). In practice, the constants matter a lot.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat interesting structure, did not know about it. Might be worth it were a real problem and not an online one